# Unable to check checkbox after angular response

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox, mean-stack

I'm making a todo app using MEAN stack. Till now I have completed with displaying the todo list and deletion of todo on click of checkbox. Now I'm trying to enhance my code by doing logical deletion. I'm using a flag in database which will toggle on the click of checkbox.

But the problem I'm facing is, the checkbox is not remaining checked. Like I click on the checkbox, then a strike-through appears. Between this, the event goes to the database change the flag and comes back. But till that time, the checked thing is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can impplement checkbox like this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkValue"  ng-true-value="'true'" ng-false-value="'false'">
```

and in controller

> $scope.checkValue = true; //makes checkbox selected

Comment: You won't need `ng-true-value` or `ng-false-value` if you set it to `true` or `false`

Comment: The above answer is not working. It is doing the same thing. Unchecking immediately after it is checked and done with strikethrough. I tried with this alert($scope.checkValue); but it is alerting to be undefined.  Please help.

Comment: Can you include your code how you have implemented that

Comment: The problem got solved. The problem was in the angularjs version being used by me. Now there is some other problem. The problem is when I click on checkbox the checkbox.checked value returned is false.

Comment: Done with the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="done" id="{{ todo.id }}" ng-model="isdone" ng-init="isdone=todo.done === 1 ? true : false" ng-click="updateTodo($event, todo.id)" />
```

I binded the ng-model properly using ng-model and ng-init and got the correct values. And even the checkbox checked stuff which was not working previously. I used the below tag first and was getting errors.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="done" id="{{ todo.id }}" ng-model="isdone" ng-click="updateTodo($event, todo.id)" />
```